# Initializing a static const array of const strings in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, initialization, constants

I am having trouble initializing a constant array of constant strings.

From week.h (showing only relevant parts):

```
class Week {
  private:
    static const char *const *days = { "mon", "tue", "wed", "thur",
                                       "fri", "sat", "sun" };
};
```

When I compile I get the error "excess elements in scalar initializer". I tried making it type const char **, thinking I messed up the 2nd const placement, but I got the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have two pointer declarations?

Comment: Not really sure at all, but does `static const char * days[] = {` help or will it break your strings from being const?

Comment: I second Tim's question!

Comment: @Tim : If a C-string is a `char*`, then a C-array of C-strings must be `char**`.

Comment: An array of C-strings is type char**, I just didn't realize I couldn't initialize it with that type.

Comment: @Nick, @Tim: a constant `C-String` is of type `const char* const`

Comment: _"An array of C-strings is type char**"_ No it's not. You are confusing arrays with pointers. As is ildjarn, apparently.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First of all, you need an array, not a pointer.

```
static const char * const days[] = {"mon", "tue", "wed", "thur",
                                       "fri", "sat", "sun"};
```

Second of all, you can't initialize that directly inside the class definition. Inside the class definition, leave only this:

```
static const char * const days[]; //declaration
```

Then, in the .cpp file, write the definition

```
const char * const Week::days[] = {"mon", "tue", "wed", "thur",
                                       "fri", "sat", "sun"};
```

**Update for C++11**
Now you can initialize members directly in the class definition:

```
const char * const days[] = {"mon", "tue", "wed", "thur",
                                       "fri", "sat", "sun"};
```

Comment: Actually you can update your answer for C++11, so you can do it in the class declaration.

Comment: Is a static array like this what you'd recommend for a set of strings like these weekday names? Is there a best practice for this sort of situation?

Answer (score 19):

For **C++11**, you **can** make the initialisation inside your class declaration, in your ***.h*** file. However, you will need to include constexpr in your ***.cpp*** file too. Example for the case above:

In your week.h file, write:

```cc
class Week {
    public:        
       static const constexpr char* const days[] = 
           { "mon", "tue", "wed", "thur","fri", "sat", "sun" };
};
```

In your week.cpp file, write somewhere:

```
constexpr const char* const Week::days[];
```

Make sure you enable **C++11**, e.g. compile with

> g++ -std=c++11 week.cpp

Comment: This was very helpful. Do you know the fundamental reason why the bit in the .cpp file is necessary? This looks very strange and unlike typical c++ (the declaration looks like a definition and vice versa). My best guess is that the in-class initialization is initializing the *elements* of the array, but not the array itself, and that's what the .cpp part is doing, but I have no real faith in this.

In general in C++11, I thought it was possible to initialize static constexpr's of any time purely in the class definition so I don't see why the .cpp part is necessary at all.

Comment: The first const is redundant I believe.